# Deriving a lower bound on the conditional entropy, conditioned on an event

Tags: probability-theory, randomized-algorithms, information-theory, entropy, communication-complexity

I came across Lemma 19 in [Certifying Equality With Limited Interaction](https://drops.dagstuhl.de/opus/volltexte/2014/4722/), which states the following for jointly distributed random variables $Z$, $W$, where $Z$ takes values in $\{0,1\}^n$, and some arbitrary event $\mathcal{E}$:
$$
H[ Z \mid W ] \ge n - d\ \Longrightarrow\ H[ Z \mid W, \mathcal{E}] \ge n - \frac{d+1}{\Pr[\mathcal{E}]}.
$$

The proof is very short, but I'm unable to follow one of the derivations, which seems to be using a general property of conditional entropy that I'm unfamiliar with.

**Proof of Lemma 19:** We know that the entropy of $Z$ can be at most $n$ no matter on what we condition. Let $H_b$ denote the binary entropy. It follows that
$$
\begin{align}
n -d &\le H[ Z \mid W] \\
     &= \Pr[ \mathcal{E} ] H[Z \mid W, \mathcal{E}] + \Pr[\neg \mathcal{E}]\ H[Z \mid W, \neg \mathcal{E}] + H_b(\Pr[\mathcal{E}]) \quad (2)\\
     &\le \Pr[ \mathcal{E}]\ H[Z \mid W, \mathcal{E}] + \Pr[\neg \mathcal{E}]\cdot n + 1. 
\end{align}     
$$
**QED**

**My Questions:**

1. Why does (2) hold? Is this some general property of conditional entropy?
2. How exactly is $H[ Z \mid W, \mathcal{E} ]$ defined? Is it equivalent to $\sum_w \Pr[W=w\mid \mathcal{E}]\ H[ Z \mid W=w,\mathcal{E}]$ or $\sum_w \Pr[W=w]\ H[ Z \mid W=w,\mathcal{E}]$?

Comment: Fixed the reference to the lemma in the paper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We treat $\mathcal{E}$ as an indicator random variable for the event $\mathcal{E}$ (so $\mathcal{E}$ stands for two different things). The derivation is
$$
H(Z|W) \leq H(Z,\mathcal{E}|W) = H(Z|\mathcal{E},W) + H(\mathcal{E}|W) \leq H(Z|\mathcal{E},W) + H(\mathcal{E}).
$$